# Delete file from a FTP server using Java

Tags: java, ftp, delete-file

I am writing an application that involves multiple clients. One client uploads a file using FTP to a server, and then another client downloads the file and deletes it. I am using the FTP server kind of as a middleman to exchange information because I do not want the user to have to port forward. I have figured out how to upload a file, but I cannot figure out how to delete the file. The command for deleting a file using FTP is:

```
DELE <filename>
```

I have tried doing so, but with no success. Here is the code that I have tried:

```
public static void deleteFile(String name) throws IOException
{
    URL url = new URL("ftp://a1111111:password@mywebsite.com/public_html/misc/screenshots/picture.png;type=i");
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(url.openConnection().getOutputStream()));
    writer.write("DELE picture.png");
    writer.flush();
}
```

I have a feeling that the < filename > that I provided may be wrong because I did not include the directory names in the path. However, since I explicitly told the path that of the file in the URL, I am not quite sure what I am supposed to enter for the < filename >.

I have read other questions on this web site about problems very similar to this and all of the responses tell to use a library. The thing is, most of those libraries are written in pure Java so the developers of that library had to figure out a way to do what I am trying to do without a library. I want to do that as well. I do not like attaching extra files besides my own to the things that I make. So please, do not tell me to use a library - it's not what I'm looking for.

If you need any clarification, please ask!

**EDIT:** If I use this code to receive a response:

```
    byte[] response = new byte[conn.getInputStream().available()];
    conn.getInputStream().read(response);
    System.out.println("Response: " + new String(response));
```

My command just gets echoed back:

```
Response: DELE test1.png
```

Comment: Are you confident that you can actually run multiple FTP commands (`GET` _and_ `DELE`) from a single funny `URL` object? It seems highly unlikely to me. What exception is thrown or what is the reply from the server? (Run Wireshark to watch the transaction, if you haven't already.)

Comment: I am not sure if this is normal or not, but after writing that DELE command, I received a 68 from the input stream established through the connection. Edit: after trying the response with different code, the input stream just echoes back what I write to it.

Comment: `68`? that's funny. [FTP status codes are three digits long.](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc959.txt).

Comment: Unrelated to your concrete problem, `InputStream#available()` really doesn't do what you think it does. Back to your problem, use a normal FTP client. It'll be so much easier for you than homegrowing one. Apache Commons Net has one, like as mentioned in the deleted answer which you downvoted.

Comment: I understand that. I looked through the source of the Apache Commons Net and found the FTPClient.deleteFile(String) method. That whole operation can be condensed down into 10 lines. 10 lines that I unfortunately cannot make work. Anyways, I do not want to attach an extra megabyte to my source for what could be 100 bytes worth of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to do the retrieve and delete in two separate operations; [some random documentation I found for `FtpURLConnection`](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/sun/net/www/protocol/ftp/FtpURLConnection.html) says, in part:

> This class Opens an FTP input (or output) stream given a URL. It works as a one shot FTP transfer :
>
> Login
>      Get (or Put) the file
>      Disconnect

I did not see any methods in the documentation that would allow deleting a file.

You may wish to use the `URL` mechanism to retrieve the file, but I would drop down to using raw sockets to delete the file. Create a new connection to the FTP command port, log in, and issue the `DELE` command manually. If this is the only step you're taking, you might be able to get away with doing relatively poor error handling and maybe only two `read()` requests and simply show the output transcript to the user once you're done.

It's a bit dirty, but I completely understand not wanting to carry around a megabyte of additional source to achieve the moral equivalent of `echo -e "user foo\npass password\ndele /path/to/file\nlogout" | nc ftp.remote.example.com 21`.

Comment: How would I go about establishing a socket connection to a server using FTP?

Comment: Just read [RFC 959, the FTP specification](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc959.txt). Lot of others have already implemented it in Java for you.

Answer (score -2):

Can you use some FTP clients to do the operation?

You can try http://commons.apache.org/net/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html from the Apache commons-net. It is easy to use.